# SQL statement to change the value of a column with that same column in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database and I've changed my mind and instead of a column in my table being set as an `int`, I want to change it to a `varchar`. So I changed the type to `varchar(8)`, and saved my changes in SQL Server Management Studio tool (V17.0).

It looks like the tool converted the int values to varchars when I saved the changes. I want to change the value of '1' to 'External', '2' to 'SPTR' and '3' to 'Other'.  I was going to do one value at a time.

This is the simple SQL statement I tried:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET mycolumn = 'External' 
WHERE mycolumn = '1'
```

The error message I get from SSMS is

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'External' to data type int"

It's as if the database thinks the type is `int`, but it's not, it's `varchar(8)`.

Comment: If that query produced that error, mycolumn isn't a varchar(8); it's an int.

Comment: As @DavidBrowne-Microsoft your change didn't stick. Here is the TSQL `alter table mytable alter column mycolumn varchar(8) null`. Then run your update again.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you really haven't changed the data type. This *should* resolve the problem.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn varchar(8);
GO
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = CASE mycolumn WHEN '1' THEN 'External'
                             WHEN '2' THEN 'SPTR'
                             ELSE 'OTHER'
               END;
```

Note, as well, you can update every value at the same time by using a `CASE` expression. Likely far easier than 3 `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: So I ran just the alter table command in the SQL Server Management tool, and that ran fine.  I then ran the Update command and it comes back with the same error.  Not sure what's going on.  I even got out of SSM tool and rebooted my system (know that it probably wouldn't help), but I'm still not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Are you including the `GO` @mdmenard (not that it should make a difference)? I [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86113b4e8ba8f57d1d55af9c53c1f6fb) the problem.

Comment: Yes, I had the GO statement as well.

Comment: Then i stand by my statement of that i can't replicate the issue, @mdmenard .David Browne is probably thinking along the right path of there is a trigger, or something, on the table that you haven't told us about.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn varchar(50);
```

`SELECT DATALENGTH ('External')`

returns 8

As long as I know varchar does not use all 50 bytes, it only uses 8 in your case to store "External" field, why don't you try to change table size.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed `mycolumn` to a string, then the following should work:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET mycolumn = 'External' 
WHERE mycolumn = '1';
```

If you are getting a type conversion error, then I assume you have a trigger on the table that is causing the problem.  You might be wrong in saying that the type has changed.  But even if you are correct, a trigger could still generate this issue.